# Grid Search and computer in sleep mode

Tags: python, machine-learning, grid-search, gridsearchcv

Does the grid search cv stops when my computer is in sleep mode? Should I turn off sleep mode when running it?

Regards
Vikrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep mode suspends all processor activities and places RAM in a low power state only enough to retain the state. So, yes grid search or any process for that matter is suspended.

Comment: Follow up question: Does it pick up where it left off if Mac is taken out of sleep mode?